# Is there an Event Listener for receiving push notifications in Windows (phone) 8.1?

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have a messages module in my app. When the app is open and the user is in the messages module I want to refresh the messages when I receive a push (toast) notification about a new message.

The push notifications are handled by the Windows OS but is there an Event Listener to notify about new notifications for my app.

I can handle a click on the notification so the new message is opened. But I want to know when the OS received the notification from my app.

Is there a way to this for Windows Store and Phone 8.1 apps?